# comando laravel que me ejecute un blade

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

hola quiero crear un comando en laravel que se ejecute una vez a la semana que me llame un blade, que tiene un script y que combina ajax y php el cual me genera unas imagenes 
el comando ya lo tengo como php artisan img::imagenes

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Commands;

    use App\Commands\Command;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;

    class imagenes extends Command implements SelfHandling
    {
        /**
         * Create a new command instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Execute the command.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function handle()
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

Comment: Una pregunta, que hace tu script y/o tu ajax, ya que esa parte tienes que programarlo en php.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [crear comando que envie datos a un blade](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143450/crear-comando-que-envie-datos-a-un-blade)

Comment: si lo se pero no la contestraron y es urgente era por si no entendian el codigo, el script genera una url de un grafico desde higchart y el php descarga la imagen y la guarda en una carpeta laravel

Comment: Todas las preguntas que publican en StackOverflow son urgentes, así que no ganas nada con duplicarlas, salvo que termine siendo cerrada una de las dos preguntas y que recibas votos negativos.

Comment: beuno es la primera vez que uso esto asi que lo siento si puse otra pregunta ya la elimine asi que si me pudieran ayudar se los agradeceria

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, pero a ver si lanzo una respuesta te ilumina ...

Si lo que tienes es un php funcionando que llama a un blade (uno.php), ¿no sería un comando del tipo php uno.php lo que necesitas ejecutar con un cron o un .bat?

Comment: Alagoro, bienvenido a SOes. Me parece que tu respuesta esta bien encaminada. Si pudieras poner un ejemplo de como hacer esto con cron (suponiendo que el OP use Linux) seria muy bueno.

Comment: la intencion es que al correr el comando me llame a un imagen.blade.php  el que por dentro tiene un script que trae una url de una imagen y la descarga en la carpeta del proyecto